# Deleting duplicates in mysql (2 tables)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (id_test, test) , each of them has an ID column, which is unique, and two entries with the same id in the two tables are the same. Now, i have another column in one of the tables (id_test) that also should be unique, so I want to eliminate duplicates according to this other column, let's call it YD.

To identify the duplicates I used

```
SELECT ID, YD AS x, COUNT(*) AS y
FROM id_test 
GROUP BY x 
HAVING y>1;
```

now, I want to delete these entries in both tables. How can I do it?

Comment: i answered already, but i am not sure, i think i need some clarifications... could you provide some sampe data? do you need to delete rows that are present both in test and in id_test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query shows the first `ID` for every `YD` in `id_test` table:

```
SELECT ID, YD
FROM id_test
GROUP BY YD
```

and these are the rows you have to keep. The following query returns the IDs you have to delete:

```
SELECT id_test.ID
FROM id_test LEFT JOIN (select ID, YD from id_test group by YD) id_test_keep
     on id_test.ID=id_test_keep.ID and id_test.YD = id_test_keep.YD
WHERE id_test_keep.ID IS NULL
```

Now I think i need more details about your tables, but what I think you need is this:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE
  test.ID IN (
    SELECT id_test.ID
    FROM id_test LEFT JOIN (select ID, YD from id_test group by YD) id_test_keep
         on id_test.ID=id_test_keep.ID and id_test.YD = id_test_keep.YD
    WHERE id_test_keep.ID IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`ALTER TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html) (emphasis added):

> `IGNORE` is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. It controls how `ALTER TABLE` works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If `IGNORE` is not specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors occur. **If `IGNORE` is specified, only the first row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted.** Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable value.

Therefore:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE id_test ADD UNIQUE (YD)
```

Comment: what about the other table? I have to delete the IDs which I identified in the first table ("id_test")

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't user select in because if data large it impossible.
You should clone a table the same structure. Insert data not duplicate in it.

***INSERT INTO test_new (ID, YD) SELECT t.ID, t.YD FROM test t LEFT JOIN test_id ti ON t.ID = ti.id WHERE ti.id IS NULL;***

After drop table test, rename test_new -> test.